# How To: Determine the distance between a point feature and the nearest point feature in same layer?

Tags: gis, distance, arcgis

I have a single shapefile that contains school locations. I want to find the distance to the nearest school for each school in the shapefile.
I'm using ArcGIS

Comment: Lots of detail missing from this question.  Do you want straight line distance or driving distance?  Do you want an attribute in the file that includes the distance and the ID of the nearest other school?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the 'NEAR' analysis tool.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm

It generates a table of near objects, in order of 'nearness'. You might have to duplicate your initial shapefile, and use the duplicate as the target. You might have to find a way to exclude the school you are currently finding nearness to. I'm not sure if you can have a range for the search radius. If you can, you could make the range not start at 0. Otherwise, you could use model builder, where you

1. Create new target feature class with all schools except current
2. Calculate near table
3. Delete the target feature class you just made

and you could use this model for each school.